# For any $U \in \mathcal{U},$ there exists a unique $x$ such that $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Suppose that $X$ is a Polish space and $F$ is a closed subset of $X.$

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.

For any function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, $ let $D^1(f,\varepsilon,F) = \{ x\in F: \forall \text{ open } U_x \ni x, \exists x_1,x_2 \in F ∩ U_x \text{ such that } |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \geq \varepsilon \}.$

[In this paper](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matlhh/preprints/54%20Ordinal%20ranks.pdf), proof of Lemma $2.2,$ page $3,$ the authors mentioned the following:

> If $x\in F\setminus D^{1}(f,\varepsilon,F),$ there exists an open neighborhood
>   $U_{x}$ of $x$ in $F$ such that $U_{x}\cap D^{1}( f,\varepsilon,F) =\emptyset$
>   and that $\vert f( x_{1}) -f( x_{2}) \vert<\varepsilon\text{ for all }%
> x_{1},\,x_{2}\in U_{x}.$ The collection
>   $$\mathcal{U}=\{ U_{x}:x\in F\setminus D^{1}( f,\varepsilon,F) \}$$
>   is an open cover of the paracompact space $F\setminus D^{1}( f,\varepsilon,F)
> $. Then there exists a (continuous)
>   partition of unity $( \varphi_{U}) _{U\in\mathcal{U}}$ subordinated to
>   $\mathcal{U}.$ If $U=U_{x}\in\mathcal{U}$ for some $x\in F\setminus D^{1}(
> f,\varepsilon,F) $, let $a_{U}=f(x)$. Define $g$ on $F\setminus D^{1}(
> f,\varepsilon,F)$ by $g=\sum_{U\in\mathcal{U}}a_{U}\varphi_{U}.$ $g$ is a
>   well-defined continuous function on $F\backslash D^{1}(f,\varepsilon,F)$ since
>   $\{ \text{supp}\,\varphi_{U}:U\in\mathcal{U}\} $ is locally finite.

**Question**: Why can we let $a_U = f(x)$ where $U = U_X?$ For any given $U\in\mathcal{U},$ it may be a neighbourhood of several points. Then which point should we choose for $a_U?$ It seems to me that $a_U$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is strictly speaking not well-defined, but the point is that for every $x, y ∈ U$ we have $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert < ε$. So formally, for every $U ∈ \mathcal{U}$ we choose some $x_U ∈ U$ and use it for definition of $α_U$. Later in the proof when the authors say “let $U = U_y$ for some $y$”, I think they really mean this chosen $x_U$.